# how to determine all tasks done when calling an async method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
- (void)downloadUrls:(NSArray *)urls completionBlock:(void(^)(NSArray *results))completionBlock {
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
    BOOL finishAll = NO;
    for(NSString *url in urls) {
        [Downloader startFetch:url completion:^(id response){
            [results addObject:response];
        }];
    }
    if(finishAll){
        completionBlock(results);
    }
}
```

I need to download many urls with this method, and if all urls has downloaded, calling the completionBlock, however, the `startFetch:` is an async method, so is there's any way to determine all tasks have done in order to call the completionBlock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not inside `downloadURLs:completionBlock:`, no, but you can check whether you're on the last item inside `startFetch:completion:`'s completion block.

```
[Downloader startFetch:url completion:^(id response){
        [results addObject:response];
        if( [results count] == [urls count] ){
            completionBlock(results);
        }
}];
```

or

```
NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];
id lastURL = [results lastObject];
for(NSString *url in urls) {
    [Downloader startFetch:url completion:^(id response){
        [results addObject:response];
        if( url == lastURL ){
            completionBlock(results);
        }
    }];
}
```